# Get SelectedItem from ListBox

Tags: xaml, windows-8, listbox, selecteditem

I want to get the SelectedItem from a ListBox which looks like this inside my Windows 8 Store App:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" Foreground="Black" BorderThickness="0" Background="#FFD8D8D8" />
```

The problem is, that the ListBox don't fire the SelectedItem propertie. I have to use *IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"* but then an error appears which says the true isn't supportet for this property. What do I have to do or are there any other ways to get the SelectedItem propertie?

I have this Code behind:

```
namespace ExampleApp
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private object currentItem;

        //Constructor and so on

        public object SelectedItem
        {
            get { Debug.WriteLine("get"); return currentItem; }
            set { Debug.WriteLine("set"); currentItem = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass listbox selecteditem as command parameter in a button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257516/how-to-pass-listbox-selecteditem-as-command-parameter-in-a-button)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should try this

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=YourPageName,path=DataContext.SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" Foreground="Black" BorderThickness="0" Background="#FFD8D8D8" />
```

Comment: Thank you it works great. I had to remove the DataContext bevor SelectedItem and now it works wunderful.

Comment: Wow. Thanks. I suppose there is a reason why Microsoft did not implement reasonable OneWayToSource binding on SelectedItem, but I can't think of one.