# ListBox.ContextMenu Get Selected Item via Command

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have this View:

```
<StackPanel>
<StackPanel.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel />
</StackPanel.DataContext>
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" x:Name="xamlPersonList">
    <ListBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="EMail" Command="{Binding WriteMailCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=xamlPersonList,Path=SelectedItem}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListBox.ContextMenu>
</ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

I want to get the selected item (or the clicked item) and do some stuff with it inside my Command-Method. This is my Ctor and Command-Method of my ViewModel:

```
public ICommand WriteMailCommand { get; private set; }
public MainViewModel()
{
    _persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        _persons.Add(new Person()
        {
            ID = i,
            Name = "Robert " + i
        });
    }

    WriteMailCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(WriteMailMethod);
}

private void WriteMailMethod(object obj)
{
}
```

The obj parameter is always null. I don't know what I am missing here?! I tried this solution: [How to pass listbox selecteditem as command parameter in a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257516/how-to-pass-listbox-selecteditem-as-command-parameter-in-a-button)

Comment: is your command `WriteMailMethod` being hit? ie its hit but with a null parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The binding isn't working because the `ContextMenu` [exists outside of your control's visual tree](http://www.wpftutorial.net/ContextMenu.html), and so it's impossible for it to find the `ListBox`.  In fact I'm surprised it's invoking your command without the usual incantation to get the data context of the associated control:

```
<ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" >
```

Regardless, you can use the [answer suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11339065/1698557), or I can suggest an alternate implementation: add a `SelectedPerson` property to your view-model:

```
private Person selectedPerson;
public Person SelectedPerson 
{ 
    get { return selectedPerson; } 
    set
    {
        selectedPerson = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(); // or whatever your implementation is
    }
}
```

Your XAML would be simple, too:

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}">
    <ListBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="EMail" 
                      Command="{Binding WriteMailCommand}" 
                      CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedPerson}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListBox.ContextMenu>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Wow okay, that works. I hope I understood it correctly. The ListBox is bound to my SelectedPerson and the CommandParameter always just put my SelectedPerson to my Method as parameter, right?! In this case I could just rely on my SelectedPerson property. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @DoubleVoid Yep, exactly.  Happy to help.

Comment: Sometimes the SelectedPerson is null, since I am right clicking the list entry to get my context menu. Is there a workaround for this too?!

Comment: Never mind, it has nothing to do with the WPF ListView. I am updating my List every 10 seconds, this removes the selection unfortunately <.< Raising a PropertyChange kills my selection.